# Can I add a tutorial to the RStudio IDE?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-package, learnr

Is there a way to add custom tutorials to the RStudio IDE?  If so, where can I find instructions? I have written learnr tutorials and my students currently do them on a positconnect server. I would like to share them with the world in a package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered on [Posit Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-do-i-add-a-tutorial-to-the-rstudio-ide/173313/2), the [Publishing Basics](https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/articles/publishing.html) article on [the learnr webpage](https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/) has instructions for publishing tutorials within R packages. Once the packages is installed, the IDE will find the tutorials and include them in the listing in the Tutorials pane.